# SQL SELECT with JOIN also records with no correspondence on second table

Tags: mysql

I have to tables: `USERS` and `DATA`. Every `user` from `USERS` can have one, multiple `rows` on `DATA` but also any.

I would like to select also the `users` from `USERS` without correspondence on `DATA` but the following query omit them. How should I modify it?

```
SELECT USERS.id,
       USERS.email,
       USERS.active,
       USERS.last_alert,
       DATA.active,
       DATA.active_from
FROM USERS
JOIN DATA
WHERE DATA.id_user = USERS.id
    AND DATA.active = 1
ORDER BY USERS.id ASC
```

`DATA.id_user` contains the `USERS.id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

```
SELECT
    USERS.id,
    USERS.email,
    USERS.active,
    USERS.last_alert,
    DATA.active,
    DATA.active_from
FROM USERS
    LEFT JOIN DATA ON (
        DATA.id_user = USERS.id AND DATA.active = 1
    )
ORDER BY USERS.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Do Outer Join

```
SELECT USERS.id,
       USERS.email,
       USERS.active,
       USERS.last_alert,
       DATA.active,
       DATA.active_from
FROM DATA
LEFT OUTER JOIN USERS
WHERE DATA.id_user = USERS.id
    AND DATA.active = 1
ORDER BY USERS.id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it as a `LEFT JOIN` should include those rows, but not available values will become `NULL` then

```
SELECT USERS.id,
       USERS.email,
       USERS.active,
       USERS.last_alert,
       DATA.active,
       DATA.active_from
FROM USERS
LEFT JOIN DATA ON USERS.id = DATA.id_user AND DATA.active = 1
ORDER BY USERS.id ASC
```